# Populate simple listview

Tags: vb.net

listView1 is set to details and have 2 columns. So I want to populate listView1 with number1 and number2. Each number should figure in its respective column. But I don't know how to do that, so please help.

Thank you.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim myItem As New ListViewItem
    Dim number1 As Decimal
    Dim number2 As Decimal
    Dim rand As New Random

    listView1.Items.Clear()

    For a As Integer = 1 To 20
        number1 = rand.Next(1, 20 + 1)
        number2 = rand.Next(1, 20 + 1)
        If number1 Mod number2 = 0 Then
            'put number1 and number2 in listview1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Listviews contain [ListViewItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Plutonix Do you ever sleep? ;)

Comment: @Plutonix: I did read your comment, but didn't know what to do. I'm sorry.

Comment: 1. Follow link to MSDN  2. Read article, learn.  3. Study examples 4. Profit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below assume you already have added two columns to your listview

If so, this should do it.

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim myItem As New ListViewItem
    Dim number1 As Decimal
    Dim number2 As Decimal
    Dim rand As New Random

    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    For a As Integer = 1 To 20
        number1 = rand.Next(1, 20 + 1)
        number2 = rand.Next(1, 20 + 1)
        If number1 Mod number2 = 0 Then
            Dim newRow As New ListViewItem(number1.ToString)
            newRow.SubItems.Add(number2.ToString)
            ListView1.Items.Add(newRow)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

If you dont already have two columns then you either need to add them in control's properties in the Visual Studio designer, or somewhere appropriate in your code - not in the button click event of course, because this will keep adding columns every time you click the button.

If you're not sure how to do this programattically - try this : -

```
ListView1.Columns.Add("number1")
ListView1.Columns.Add("number2")
```

The names of the columns can be anything in quotes. The fact that I chose "numbers1" and "numbers2" isn't important

I can't tell you where to put this in your code, but a good bet would be in the form.load event

Comment: If somebody's answer works for you, click on the tick next to it. - It helps other users who are searching for solutions. They can see that an answer to a question has been accepted and may work for them. And of course the person that answered the question gets reputation - And you get 2 rep for accepting as well!

Comment: I clicked on it the moment I saw your answer, but I haven't the minimum points. Once I have it, I'll do it. Thank you again for your help, that allowed me to go ahead in my learning.

Comment: I thought everyone was able to click the tick to the left of an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I clicked on the arrow above to give to rep you. I did it now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hehe No problem. Thanks.